# Yiistrap: Dropdown option not getting passed to the database. I get validation errors

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii-extensions

I wanted to use dropdown menu in my form to enter the category of books but the data is not getting passed and I get validation errors when I'm using Yii with Yiistrap.

Here is how my code looks like.. this in protected/views/books/_form.php

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListControlGroup($model, 'book_category',
        array('New', 'Used', 'Reference'), array('empty' => 'Select Category')); ?>
```

when I enter the data I get validation errors. Is there any way that I can pass the data without validation errors ?

Please help

Comment: Can you post the model code?

Comment: here's the model code [link](http://pastebin.com/Ge0PuHRe)

Comment: Which validation errors you get?

Comment: @jonijones its says minimum length should be 3 characters. Of course I only specified the rule

Comment: If you select `New` - `book_category` will be `0`, `Used` - `1`, `Reference` - `2`. So, you need change your validation rule for `book_category`

Comment: @jonijones thanks solved the issue.